# How do I write to a file in 16 bits?

Tags: python

I have opened a file in binary mode, and did some calculations with the data. Now I want to write it to a file (also opened in binary mode), but as the number is in a string, I need to convert it to a 16 bit code word that is stored in the file with two bytes. How should I do so?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. What is the deal with this code word? What have you tried? Where is the code you tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

[`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) converts Python `int` values to binary coding.

```
import struct
your_value_to_write = 9876 # (or any other value: 0 <= value <= 2**16)
outputfile.write(struct.pack("<H",9876))
```

Comment: What is the '<' in front of H used for ?

Comment: @user3747200: if you read the linked documentation, it will answer that question.